# How to detect if a GPS coordinate fall in an area on MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

In my App i have an Array of Coordinates(CLLocationCoordinate2D) of perimeter of a circle. And now i am getting a coordinate from somewhere and i need to check if the new coordinate fall inside the circle.
And if it does i just wan to show a pin on that coordinate and basically it should fall under the area.
How should i go about checking this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say if your array of coordinates was just latitude and longitudes, `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structures, or `CLLocation` objects, but if you create a `CLLocation` object (if you don't already have one), you can then call [`distanceFromLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW18) to see how far away it is from another location. I'm assuming that, in addition to the array of coordinates for the perimeter, you also have the coordinate for the center?

If you have `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, you could therefore do:

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude
                                                  longitude:coordinate.longitude];

CLLocation *centerLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:centerCoordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:centerCoordinate.longitude];

CLLocationDistance distance = [location distanceFromLocation:centerLocation];
```

Chatting with you offline, it sounds like the array of coordinates on the map are a result of a user gesture (which explains why you didn't have the center of the circle of coordinates).

Given that this is the case, rather than using the mapping methods to try to figure out whether a region contains a coordinate, I'd suggest using the Quartz methods for testing whether a `CGPoint` in a view is contained within a closed `UIBezierPath`, which we'll construct from the user's gesture.

Thus:

- Build a `UIBezierPath` as the user drags their finger across the screen;
- When done, compare the resulting path against the coordinate in question. For example, the map view is showing the user location, you can look at the `userLocation` property of the map, convert its coordinate from a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to view coordinates in a view using the map view's `convertCoordinate:toPointToView` method).
- Having the `CGPoint` within the mapview for the user's current location, we can now use the `UIBezierPath` instance method, `containsPoint` to test to see if the point is within the bezier path.

Thus, that might look like:

```
- (void)turnOnGestureForView:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
    mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [mapView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void)turnOffGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture map:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
    [mapView removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    static UIBezierPath *path;
    static CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;

    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        if (!shapeLayer)
        {
            shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
            [self.mapView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
        }
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path moveToPoint:location];
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        [path addLineToPoint:location];
        shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        MKMapView *mapView = (MKMapView *)gesture.view;

        [path addLineToPoint:location];
        [path closePath];
        CGPoint currentLocation = [mapView convertCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.coordinate
                                                    toPointToView:gesture.view];
        if ([path containsPoint:currentLocation])
            NSLog(@"%s path contains %@", __FUNCTION__, NSStringFromCGPoint(currentLocation));
        else
            NSLog(@"%s path does not contain %@", __FUNCTION__, NSStringFromCGPoint(currentLocation));

        [shapeLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        shapeLayer = nil;

        // if you want to turn off the gesture and turn scrolling back on, you can do that now

        [self turnOffGesture:gesture map:mapView];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that.Its CLLocationCoordniate2D.

Comment: I do not have coordinate for the center. Also even if i get the distance how can i tell if its under the boundary or not. Please explain i know where you are going but still can't think of it in code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23809/discussion-between-rob-and-ashutosh)